# Breakpoint on memory access in ARM debugging

Tags: ida, arm, hardware, breakpoint

I'm using IDA Pro for ARM native debugging (with androidserver). I'd like to check when a memory address is read by code (what instruction and where). Hardware breakpoint is not possible. How can I do it? How to use watch option? With `gdb`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called `watchpoints`/`memory breakpoints`.
Sadly, IDA doesn't let you place memory breakpoints.

Fortunately, you can implement those by changing the page protection and catching the page protection violation exception as described [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19317/monitor-all-changes-done-by-function/19318#19318) and [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8955/set-memory-breakpoing-on-access-on-a-section-in-ida).

Comment: Thanks amirag. Can you help me to understand how to do? Can you give an example with ida? I'd like to stop or trace when a code location is read. Many thanks

Comment: doing it by hand will go something like that: shift+f7, right click on the segment that contains the address you want.and make it non-readable. continue execution until you get an exception. if the cause is not a read instruction to the address you want, just continue execution. if it is,  you can have a lok at the code and stuff. don't forget that when you continue execution you should change the permissions back, step one instruction and remove the read permission again

Comment: changing segment permissions in IDA does nothing to the running process, it's just internal flags for analaysis/decompiler.

Comment: so ignore my oh, i see. so that's pretty much nullifies my suggestion

Comment: Thus, How I can do in order to find what instruction goes to read a single location? By stepping all code is very hard...